# How to know in which file it is a referenced fp is currently writing in?

Tags: c, file, ansi-c, byref

The idea is, main opens few files, and writes to them given a condition, fp is passed by ref here and there, and writeresult is responsible to save in the actual file.
Can we know in which file it is writing ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Write2File(char *iMessage, FILE *fp)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", iMessage);

    // can i know in here where it is printing ?
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3, *fp4;
    char message[250];

    memset(message, '\0', 250);

    strncpy(message, "sample text", 10);

    fp1 = fopen("./output1.txt", "w+");
    fp2 = fopen("./output2.txt", "w+");
    fp3 = fopen("./output3.txt", "w+");
    fp4 = fopen("./output4.txt", "w+");

    Write2File(message, fp1);
    Write2File(message, fp2);
    Write2File(message, fp3);
    Write2File(message, fp4);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    fclose(fp4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OS specific and there is no standard way.  If you want to do it consistently you can define some data structure that will hold pathname along FILE handle and pass that around instead of plain FILE:

```
struct file_handle {
  FILE *fs;
  char *path;
};
```

Usually, there is no direct correspondence between a file stream and a disk file.  For example on Linux, a file stream can be associated with something that is not a disk file (device, socket, pipe) or a disk file which is accessible through many different names in the file system or has been deleted and is no longer accessible.
On the other hand you can use /proc file system to check which files correspond  to different file descriptors. This is how vim instance editing /etc/hosts looks like through /proc lenses:

```
# ls -l /proc/8932/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Feb 24 18:36 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Feb 24 18:36 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Feb 24 18:36 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 Feb 24 18:36 4 -> /etc/.hosts.swp
```

Comment: For the record, I don't think there's a direct correspondence between a file stream and a disk file in any operating system that I know of (at least those that offer file streams). That doesn't mean the answer is wrong (it isn't), but as I read it it seems to imply that it is "a Linux thing" :-)

Comment: Right. I said "on Linux", because I used /dev, hardlinks and /proc in the example. I'll clarify.

Comment: Also, consider `fmemopen` which is defined by POSIX, where a file descriptor might not actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have anything to compare against, and there's no standard way to get the file from the `FILE`.

Of course, there are always implementation-specific ways to dig out the data if you really want to, for debugging nd the like.

Anyway, why should your sub-routine care?
You better have some really good reason for such a severe breach of encapsulation.

Comment: basically it is to keep statistics for how many times a file was accessed for write.

Comment: In that case, things are simple: Make your stat-collector aware of your `FILE`s when you open/close them, and call that stat-updater with the file-handle where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't in C. 
But you can take FILE pointers as global and compare them in your function Write2File().

```
FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3, *fp4;
void Write2File(char *iMessage, FILE *fp)
{
    if(fp==fp1)
        printf("output1.txt\n");
    else if(fp==fp2)
        printf("output2.txt\n");
    else if(fp==fp3)
        printf("output3.txt\n");
    else if(fp==fp4)
        printf("output4.txt\n");    

    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", iMessage);


}
```

Alternatively you can add an extra parameter to your Write2File() function to know which file it is refering to

```
void Write2File(char *iMessage, FILE *fp, int i)
{
    char filename[12];
    char file[2];
    itoa(i, file, 10);
    strcpy(filename, "output");
    strcat(filename,file);
    strcat(filename,".txt");
    printf("--%s--", filename);

}

Write2File(message, fp1, 1);
Write2File(message, fp2, 2);
Write2File(message, fp3, 3);
Write2File(message, fp4, 4);
```

Comment: thats not gonna work as at the time of call of Write2File I already have a referenced fp and it is dynamic call to dynamic fp

Comment: Then you can take FILE pointers global, and try comparing them in Write2File(). Should work. See my edited answer.